# Cannot TLS connect to GCP Cloud SQL(MySQL) using python3

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-sql

```
import ssl

sc = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
sc.load_verify_locations(cafile='./server-ca.pem')
sc.load_cert_chain(certfile='./client-cert.pem', keyfile='./client-key.pem')

#sc.check_hostname = False

async with aiomysql.create_pool(
    host=host,
    port=port,
    user=user,
    password=password,
    db=db,
    ssl=sc
)
```

I'm getting an error like this.

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not
>   valid for 'ip_address'. (_ssl.c:1108)

server-ca.pem, client-cert.pem, and client-key.pem are exported from the connection tab of GCP Cloud SQL.

```
#mysql --ssl-ca=./server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=./client-cert.pem --ssl-key=./client-key.pem --host=host --user=user --password
```

This mysql command can be used to access.

I would like you to tell me what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered the same problem. You need to set the parameter `check_hostname=False`, such that SSL doesn't try to verify it.

```
ssl = {
  'cert': ...,
  'key': ...,
  'ca': ...,
  'check_hostname': False,
}
```

I'm using PyMySQL. You might look into how that applies to SSLContext in your case.

Comment: Is the security guaranteed even if I change the hostname not to be checked?